# React Cannot access props value outside class using (props)=>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to have GoogleMapGazi access the props of my class GoogleMaps using the 'props=> ' but I cannot do it. I have passed the lat and lng props to the class by the parent component. Here's my code, any help will be great!

```
const GoogleMapGazi = withGoogleMap(props => (
  <GoogleMap
    defaultCenter={{ lat: 25.804281, lng: -80.1903893 }}
    defaultZoom={15}
  >
    <Marker position={{ lat: props.lat, lng: props.lng }} />
  </GoogleMap>
));

class GoogleMaps extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <GoogleMapGazi
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: `500px`, width: "600px" }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleMaps;
```

Comment: You are not passing the `lat` and `lng` props to the `GoogleMapGazi` component in the `GoogleMaps` parent component.

Comment: Why are you doing `props.lat`? `GoogleMapGazi` doesn't have the prop `lat` and `lng` defined, why would you expect them to be magically defined in your `GoogleMapGazi`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass down the props from the `GoogleMaps` component.

You could explicitly pass down the `lat` and `lng` props, or you can use the spread syntax to pass down all props.

```
class GoogleMaps extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <GoogleMapGazi
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: `500px`, width: "600px" }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
          {...this.props}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You sir are awesome!
Thank you very much!